# Determine what device a directory is located on

Tags: mount, directory, block-device

If I do

```
# cd /
# ln -s /home test
# cd test
# mount --bind $PWD /mnt
```

the entry in `/proc/mounts` is

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt ext4 rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

which is the device that is mounted to `/home` and is not easily deducible from `$PWD` which is `/test`. How can I determine which device (i.e., /dev/sda2) is going to show up in `/proc/mounts` in general given that the bind mount may be to a directory/file that is potentially "obscured" by symlinks, other bind mounts, etc?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If I understand your question you want to know which device was used for a given mount. For this you can use the `df` command:

```
$ df -h 
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root   50G   21G   27G  44% /
devtmpfs                           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              3.8G   14M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              3.8G  984K  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                              3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                              3.8G  3.4M  3.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                          477M   99M  349M  23% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home  402G  184G  198G  49% /home
```

To find which device a particular file/directory is found on, give the file as an argument to `df`. Using your example:

```
$ df -h /mnt
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                          477M   99M  349M  23% /
```

You can also use the `mount` command:

```
$ mount | grep '^/dev'
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
```

The directory mounted for each device is the 3rd argument in the output above. So for device `/dev/sda1` would be `/boot`. The other devices are making use of LVM (Logical Volume Management) and would need to be further queried to know which actual device is being used by LVM.

Comment: If `$PWD` (which is what I am mounting) is buried in a series of symlinks, bind mounts, etc then I would need to recursively examine the path for mount points.

Comment: With bind mounts despite what shows up in `/proc/mounts` the "thing" that is mounted, at least in my mind, is not the device it is the directory/file.

Comment: @StrongBad - what does `readlink -f /mnt` show?

Comment: @StrongBad if you have to deal with determining the mount point/device when obscured by symlinks, you should put that in your question. It'll make it much easier to get the right answer.

Comment: `readlink -f /mnt` gives
`/mnt`

Comment: I think you're relegated to walking it recursively then. But just so we're clear can you please update your Q with what Patrick mentioned?

Comment: @Patrick done, I think

Comment: @StrongBad if it's a link, you could get the device name with `df $(readlink -f /path/to/file) | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`.

Comment: For the mount point of the current folder, just type: `df .`

Answer (score 71):

On Linux we have `findmnt` from `util-linux` exactly made for this

```
findmnt -n -o SOURCE --target /path/to/FILE
```

The advantage about other solutions is that it still works if paths are obscured by symlinks or duplicate bind mounts.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It shows the source of every mount on the system. findmnt from util-linux 2.23.2

Comment: @bwduncan for me it works with 2.23.2. Maybe a bug? Could you try the latest version 2.29.2?

Comment: 2.29 on Ubuntu does the trick. Not a bug as such, more a feature :)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed for a system script.

Comment: `findmnt -n -o SOURCE -M /path/to/DIR` is what is best for me, it checks for the exact mountpoint: `/path/to/DIR` , if it is not used nothing is returned. With `findmnt -n -o SOURCE --target /path/to/DIR` you get the partition where the mountpoint is located, which is the answer on the original question!

Answer (score 15):

The most accurate method I am aware of is to use the output of the lstat() system call. Specifically, the st_dev field. There is a command line utility, stat(1) that can be used to see this information. For example, the output of "stat /etc/issue" on my laptop:

```
File: ‘/etc/issue’
  Size: 65          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 1610916043  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

Notice the third line, first field, "Device". Here it lists 801h. That value can be separated into two bytes, 8 and 1. The first byte is known as the major number, the second byte is the minor number. So, the next step is to figure out what device major 8, minor 1 is.

I find consulting /proc/partitions to be the fastest. In my case, /proc/partitions has the contents:

```
major minor  #blocks  name

   8       16  234431064 sdb
   8       17   33554432 sdb1
   8       18  200875608 sdb2
   8        0  500107608 sda
   8        1  500106584 sda1
```

It's rather clear from that output that major 8, minor 1 is sda1. We can confirm this with an ls -l /dev/sda1

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 May  8 05:33 /dev/sda1
```

Notice the 8, 1 before the datestamp.

It's important to understand/remember that the name of a device file like /dev/sda1 is only a label. The major and minor numbers are the significant, important values of the device file. If you get curious, check out the mknod(1) utility used to create device files. I could create a new /dev entry called aardvark with major 8, minor 18 with the following syntax:

```
mknod /dev/aardvark b 8 18
```

Then, I could easily mount it:

```
mount /dev/aardvark /mnt
```

and, if we look at the output of the mount command or the contents of /proc/mounts and we see:

```
/dev/aardvark on /mnt type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

df -h shows:

```
/dev/aardvark   192G  154G   38G  81% /mnt
```

... Anyways, the point of all of this is to illustrate that the important details for identifying a block device are the major and minor numbers - not the device file label - and that using the lstat() system call is the best way to query those values.

As a last comment, I just reread your question to make sure I was answering it and I realized you were asking what source device label would show up in /proc/mounts for a bind mount. That would be the same source device label as was used in the original mount(2) call for the filesystem mountpoint source for the bind mount. Perhaps an example would help:

I have /dev/sdb2 and /dev/aardvark (the same as above). They are both major 8, minor 18. Note, I will be mounting the same filesystem twice. I do the following:

```
mkdir /mnt1 /mnt2 /foo

mount /dev/aardvark /mnt1
mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt2
```

Notice that I make the directory somedir in /mnt1. But since /mnt1 and /mnt2 have the same filesystem mounted, somedir will also be reachable through /mnt2.

```
mkdir /mnt1/somedir

mkdir /foo/left /foo/right

mount -o bind /mnt1/somedir /foo/left
mount -o bind /mnt2/somedir /foo/right
```

Now, if we check /proc/mounts, we see:

```
/dev/aardvark /mnt1 xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
/dev/sdb2 /mnt2 xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
/dev/aardvark /foo/left xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
/dev/sdb2 /foo/right xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
```

The source device label on the /foo/... bind mounts is the same as the value originally supplied in the filesystem mount(2) call. Remember, /dev/aardvark and /dev/sdb2 in my example are the same device.

I realize I just typed up a novel and the first half doesn't really answer your question at all, but it seemed like such a waste to delete it. Perhaps it'll help someone else.

Good Luck.

P.S. Do keep in mind that some filesystems are network based - like NFS or CIFS - or are virtual - like procfs or sysfs and don't have a source block device. I don't know what will be returned as the device in the stat output, just for what it's worth.

Comment: The first part definitely helps me understand the last part.

Comment: This answer does not work for tmpfs paths. You will not find the st_dev minor,major on /proc/partitions.

Comment: @mbello As I mention at the end of my answer, this method won't and can't work for filesystems that have no backing device - like tmpfs mounts.

Answer (score 7):

Given the following typical mountpoints:

```
$ df --output=target
Mounted on
/
/dev
/run
/sys/fs/cgroup
/run/lock
/run/shm
/run/user
```

`stat --format %m <path>` will print only mountpoint in a round-trappable fashion (although you need to check the exit code to unambiguously detect a permission error; mount-table approaches win here):

```
$ stat --format %m /
/
$ stat --format %m /tmp
/
$ stat --format %m /proc
/proc
$ stat --format %m /run
/run
$ stat --format %m /run/mount
/run
$ stat --format %m /run/user
/run/user
$ stat --format %m /run/user/1000/dconf
/run/user
$ stat --format %m /run/user/1000/gvfs
/run/user/1000/gvfs
```

Symlinks take a bit of care as usual:

```
$ ls -lh ~/.gvfs
/home/cwillu/.gvfs -> /run/user/1000/gvfs
$ stat --format %m ~/.gvfs
/run/user/1000/gvfs
$ stat --format %m ~/.gvfs
/
```

And of course remember to use quotes when scripting.  Consider a mountpoint path with spaces and such:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/Something\ Like\ This\!
$ sudo mount none /tmp/Something\ Like\ This\! -t tmpfs
$ stat --format %m /tmp/Something\ Like\ This\!
/tmp/Something Like This!
$ touch /tmp/Something\ Like\ This\!/pretend-I\'m-big
$ ls /tmp/Something\ Like\ This\!
pretend-I'm-big
```

How big *are* you?

```
$ du $(stat --format %m /tmp/Something\ Like\ This\!/)
du: cannot access /tmp/Something: No such file or directory
du: cannot access Like: No such file or directory
du: cannot access This!: No such file or directory

$ du "$(stat --format %m /tmp/Something\ Like\ This\!/)"
0   /tmp/Something Like This!
```

My distro's tab completion don't even get this right, so we'll just wildcard this example mountpoint with carriage returns and linefeeds and runs of spaces:

```
$ stat --format %m /tmp/Something*
/tmp/Something   
Like   This!

$ a="$(stat --format %m /tmp/Something*)"
    # the above assignment is actually the one place you don't need quotes, 
    # but `export a=...` or similar _would_ need them, so we'll just put them in;
    # they don't change the behaviour in this form of assignment.

$ stat "$a"
  File: ‘/tmp/Something   \r\n\rLike   This!’
  Size: 40          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 7bh/123d    Inode: 1279171     Links: 2
Access: (1777/drwxrwxrwt)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-09-30 11:43:17.933467344 -0600
Modify: 2016-09-30 11:43:17.933467344 -0600
Change: 2016-09-30 11:43:17.933467344 -0600
 Birth: -
```

Comment: The <kbd> markup is used for a single key, rather than a whole command. It doesn't look any better this way, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The `du` command can be called with an `-x` switch to ignore content from other mounted file systems.

The `-k` switch displays directory sizes in KB.

To display directories >~ 1MB in size.

```
du -xk / | awk ' $1 > 1000000 { print } '
```