# How to get the available and current disk usage in the folder I am right now

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to see the current available disk space as well as how much the folder I am in is using. Is there some du/df command that not only tells me the size of my folder but also how much is still available in this directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `df -h /YourDiskLocation` will resolve your problem, and here's an example of `df` command:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        29G   11G   17G  39% /
devtmpfs        325M     0  325M   0% /dev
tmpfs           455M     0  455M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           182M  1.3M  181M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   31M  222M  13% /boot
tmpfs            91M   20K   91M   1% /run/user/1000
```

And on `2nd` to `4rd` column, there shows `total`、 `used` and `available` size, and for example you want to see the home directory usage, like this:

```
$ df -h /home
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        29G   11G   17G  39% /
```

From the above information, `/home` is mounted on `/`, and 11G is used, 17G available.
And you can check this answers too:

[Determine what device a directory is located on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128471/determine-what-device-a-directory-is-located-on)

Hope that helped you, and hope your understand my poor English!

Comment: Thanks the last line did the trick

Answer (score 2):

You can get the size of the disk usage of the current folder with the du command, using the "s" (summarize) option:

```bash
du -sk .
```

The "k" signifies the result is in kibibytes (i.e. 1024 bytes).

To get the capacity of the disk partition that this directory resides, then you can use the df command:

```bash
df -k .
```

This command returns the capacity of the whole disk partition, not specifically this directory.

Again the results are in kibibytes, so it will be more easily comparable to the result from the du command.

Comment: Actually `-k` gives results in **kibibytes**  (but on macOS maybe it gives results in `*bytes` instead of `*bibytes`)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon - agreed we have all one time or another cursed disk vendors for usurping the word kilobyte. I have updated my answer to state kibibytes instead of kilobytes.

Comment: use `h` instead of `k` which returns in human readable form like `KB`, `MB`, `GB` etc